# How to remove locale prefix in url for default language

Tags: php, symfony, sulu

I'm starting a sulu.io project and I want urls like that (French is the default language) :

```
{host}/mon-article
{host}/en/my-article
```

My config:

```
<localizations>
    <localization language="fr" default="true"/>
    <localization language="en"/>
</localizations>
```

I've tried :

```
<environment type="dev">
     <urls>
          <url language="fr">{host}</url>
          <url>{host}/{localization}</url>
     </urls>
</environment>
```

But it redirect everything with `{host}/fr`, I can't have {host} only

Comment: the line `<url>{host}/{localization}</url>` overwrite the first one.

Comment: if you want to have both you would have to do following:

    <environment type="dev">
        <urls>
            <url language="fr">{host}</url>
            <url language="en">{host}/en</url>
        </urls>
    </environment>

Comment: I tried this too but it redirect /article to /fr/article and I get a a 404. It still works with /en/

Comment: have you also cleared the symfony cache?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use bundle JMSI18nRoutingBundle, [hear](https://codereviewvideos.com/course/getting-started-with-fosuserbundle/video/translations-and-internationalisation-in-fosuserbundle) the tutorial how to configured hem (6 minutes).

```
jms_i18n_routing:
    default_locale: "%locale%"
    locales: [ru, ua]
    strategy: prefix_except_default (!!!)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try next:

```
<environment type="dev">
     <urls>
          <url language="fr">{host}</url>
          <url language="en">{host}/en</url>
     </urls>
</environment>
```

It works for sulu 1.6.21